# TypeError: Odd-length string when decoding hex string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, hex, decode

I've made sure the string is stripped and I still get the odd-length string issue. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
>>> toSend = "FF F9 FF 00 00 FA FF F7 FF F4 FF F6 FF F7 FF F6 FF FD FF 05 00 03 00 06 00 05 00 04 00 06 00 06 00 03 00 FB FF 02 00 0B"
>>> toSend.decode("hex")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/hex_codec.py", line 42, in hex_decode
    output = binascii.a2b_hex(input)
TypeError: Odd-length string
>>>
```

Comment: have you removed white spaces?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The spaces in the string are confusing the `decode` method.  Your code will work if you remove them:

```
>>> toSend = "FF F9 FF 00 00 FA FF F7 FF F4 FF F6 FF F7 FF F6 FF FD FF 05 00 03 00 06 00 05 00 04 00 06 00 06 00 03 00 FB FF 02 00 0B"
>>> toSend.replace(' ', '').decode('hex')
'\xff\xf9\xff\x00\x00\xfa\xff\xf7\xff\xf4\xff\xf6\xff\xf7\xff\xf6\xff\xfd\xff\x05\x00\x03\x00\x06\x00\x05\x00\x04\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x03\x00\xfb\xff\x02\x00\x0b'
>>>
```

Or, if you must have them, use `str.join` and a list comprehension:

```
>>> toSend = "FF F9 FF 00 00 FA FF F7 FF F4 FF F6 FF F7 FF F6 FF FD FF 05 00 03 00 06 00 05 00 04 00 06 00 06 00 03 00 FB FF 02 00 0B"
>>> ' '.join([x.decode('hex') for x in toSend.split()])
'\xff \xf9 \xff \x00 \x00 \xfa \xff \xf7 \xff \xf4 \xff \xf6 \xff \xf7 \xff \xf6 \xff \xfd \xff \x05 \x00 \x03 \x00 \x06 \x00 \x05 \x00 \x04 \x00 \x06 \x00 \x06 \x00 \x03 \x00 \xfb \xff \x02 \x00 \x0b'
>>>
```

Comment: you can also use `binascii` `binascii.a2b_hex(toSend.replace(' ', ''))
`

Comment: this helped me! Arrigato!